# Loading data asynchronous with javascript does NOT work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I want to transfer data via JSON and receive it in a browser via ajax. The data size is about 2 mb and the problem is that firefox does not respond during receivement of the data. 
So I want to receive the data in the background, without interrupting the webinterface, but it does not seem to work.

My javascript code

```
  $.ajax({
  url: 'http://127.0.0.1:10085/data/getd',
  dataType: 'json',
  global: false,
  success: function (response) {
    // just for testing
    alert("HI");
  },
  async: true,
});
```

Maybe you can help me?

Regards

Marko

Comment: Use promises (or just google for *jquery deferred*) [handle-asynchronous-non-blocking-io-in-javascript](http://sebastianmetzger.com/handle-asynchronous-non-blocking-io-in-javascript/). Look at [javascript-promises](https://davidwalsh.name/write-javascript-promises) and at [jquery-deferred](http://www.danieldemmel.me/blog/2013/03/22/an-introduction-to-jquery-deferred-slash-promise/), both articles are referenced by the first one.

Comment: Thank you very much! Ok, I hope I will get it - it looks complicated..